# Prove a particular stochastic process is martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I know that for a stochastic process $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ to be a martingale, we need it to be:

1. $E[X_n]\leq +\infty$
2. Adapted to a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\geq 0}$
3. If $n\leq m$ then $E[X_m\mid F_n]=X_n$

I have been given a stochastic process $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ with independent increments such that $E[X_n]=0$ for all $n$. The two first points are evident if we consider $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ the natural filtration. However, I'm having trouble with the third point. The interpretation of the last point should be that the expected value of the next observations, given the last observations, should be the value of the observation that is immediately before. Given this interpretation, it's obvious that if the expected value is $0$, meaning we don't expect the outcome to change from our initial condition, it should be obvious that $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a martingale. However, I am failing at how to translate this to more mathematical terms. Any hints would be greatly appreciated. I need to show it's a martingale in respect to the natural filtration

Comment: Have you written all the information you've been given? I think you need to give more concrete information for constructive hints.

Comment: To deal with conditionnal expectation you might want the process to be integrable. Also as the above comment says you have too poor information : take $M_n$ any martingale such that $\mathbb E (M_0) \neq 0$ and $X_n = M_n - \mathbb E(X_n)$.

Comment: I have only been told that my process $X_n$ has independent increments and that I must show it is martingale in respect to the natural filtration. @Keen-ameteur

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the independance of the increments. Then use $X_{n+1} = X_{n+1} - X_n + X_n$.